How to solve a LPP problem formulated using four variables, and 3 inequalities.
Formulation of a LPP, with 4 categories of advertising means: T.V., Radio, Magazine I, Magazine II is as follows:
Let the number(#) of advertising units for Television be denoted by: $x_1,$ for Radio be denoted by: $x_2,$ for Magazine I be denoted by: $x_3,$ for Magazine II be denoted by: $x_4.$
Clearly, $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\geq 0.$
The problem further states as below, though in the problem the first fact is not used.
Fact #1 : The number of potential customers reached per unit of advertisement by the four media is:
$2,00,000; 6,00,000; 1,50,000;$ & $1,00,000$ respectively.
Fact #2 : Each advertising unit on Television costs $30,000/-,$ on Radio costs $20,000/-,$ on Magazine I costs $15,000/-,$ and on Magazine II costs $10,000/-.$
Fact #3 : The number of female customers reached with each of the four media is $1,50,000; 4,00,000; 70,000;$ and $ 50,000$ respectively.
Constraint #1 concerns with budget, for advertising being at max. $4,50,000/-.$
$C1: 30x_1 + 20x_2 + 15x_3 + 10x_4 \leq 450  \implies  6x_1 + 4x_2 + 3x_3 + 2x_4 \leq 90$
Constraint #2 concerns with female viewership, being at least 1 million.
$C2: 15x_1 + 40x_2 + 7x_3 + 5x_4 \geq 100$
Constraint #3 concerns with the total budget of the two magazines, being limited by $1,50,000/-.$
$C3: 15x_3 + 10x_4 \leq 150  \implies  3x_3 + 2x_4 \leq 30$
Constraint #4 concerns with the number of advertising units, on T.V. (#units $= x_1$) and  Radio (# units $= x_2$), being between $5, 10.$
$C4: 5\leq x_1, x_2 \leq 10$
Unable to find solution, as have lesser number of inequalities than the number of variables.
Request some hint, or approach. Will try to edit the post, and resubmit then.
Tried to find graphical solution using desmos.com, but failed as it seems to work till 3 variables only. It flags each of the inequalities.

what is the objective of your optimization problem? what have you learned? Are you supposed to just model it or solve it? are you supposed to use a software to solve it?

@SiongThyeGoh Thanks a lot. Yes, need to just model it. But, would be even more happier if could add the software part is added too.

to model it, we need to know what is your goal, i.e. what is your objective function. try to read the original problem again to figure it out. After which, try it on a software.  It seems as of now, there is no mentioning of simplex or basic solution. Hence the expectation could be just stop at modelling for now.

@SiongThyeGoh The objective function seemed obvious to me, i.e. minimize the expense on advertising; while achieving the female viewership constraint, cost limits, and other two constraints too. So, need find the number of units of each type of media campaign that minimizes the cost. Say, $C(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = 30x_1+ 20x_2 + 15x_3 + 10x_4.$ But, then it resembles very close to the first constraint, i.e $C1.$

@jiten What number is this one $1,00,000$?

@callculus42 The number of potential customers reached per unit of advertisement of the fourth media, i.e. Magazine II.

Ok,  but is it 1,000,000 or 100,000?


Graphical method is not suitable for high-dimensional problem.

If the objective function is indeed to minimize the expenses, it is alright to be the same as the LHS part of a constraint. You can minimize the expenses subject to a certain constraint on the expense. In that case, just write down the objective function. If you have defined your decision variable, objective function and the constraints, you can now solve the problem either by hand or by using a solver.


$$\min 6_1+4_2+3_3+2_4$$
subject to
$$6_1+4_2+3_3+2_4\le 90  $$
$$15_1+40_2+7_3+5_4 \ge 100$$
$$3_3+2_4\le 30$$
$$5\le _1,_2 \le 10$$
$$x_3 \ge 0, x_4 \ge 0$$

This is a relatively easy problem to solve. The variables are nonnegative. We want to use as little resources as possible and only $C_2$ has a minimal requirement to fulfilled and $x_1, x_2$ has a non-trivial lower bound. The minimal requirement can be satisfied via $(5,5,0,0)$, we verified that it is feasible, and this must be the optimal point.

To me, the objective function is unclear. In practice, if a budget has been allocated, sometimes, we care if the objective function  is maximized within the budget, we do not have to minimize the expenses. For an advertising company, typically, we care about if we can reach out to as many potential customer as possible. In that case, you will get to use fact $1$ in the objective function. You might want to formulate the objective function this way.


